# Automated creation of customer urls for GAE web application

Tags: google-app-engine

i am new to GAE and currently evaluating if i can use GAE for deploying my java web application. When my application is finished a new user has to be able to register on my website for the usage and then he gets his private url ( user1.myapp.com) with an instance of my application. Is it difficult to realize this with GAE.

best regards 
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible according to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping

After that, it's up to your application. Any decent framework you use should be able to handle multiple domains and generate content based on them.

Comment: Thanks , i read about the subdomain Mapping. Do you have any experience with other cloud Provider supporting this?

Comment: Pretty easy to do on AWS.